# F# Pipelines access data from pipeline stages above

Tags: f#

I have written a function like this

```
let GetAllDirectAssignmentsforLists (spWeb : SPWeb) =    
  spWeb.Lists 
  |> Seq.cast<SPList> 
  |> Seq.filter(fun l -> l.HasUniqueRoleAssignments) 
  |> Seq.collect (fun l -> l.RoleAssignments 
                           |> Seq.cast<SPRoleAssignment> 
                           |> Seq.map(fun ra -> ra.Member)
                 )
  |> Seq.filter (fun p -> p.GetType().Name = "SPUser")
  |> Seq.map(fun m -> m.LoginName.ToLower())
```

I want to return a tuple which contains the list name (taken from `l.Title`) in the send pipe and the `m.LoginName.ToLower()`.

Is there a cleanway for me to get something from the above pipe elements?

One way ofcourse would be to tuple the return value in the 2nd stage of the pipe and then pass the Title all the way down.... but that would pollute the code all subsequent stages will then have to accept and return tuple values just for the sake of the last stage to get the value.

I wonder if there is a clean and easy way....

Also, in stage 4 of the pipeline `(fun p -> p.GetType().Name = "SPUser")` could i use if here to compare the types? rather than convert the `typename` to `string` and then match strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We exploit the fact that `Seq.filter` and `Seq.map` can be pushed inside `Seq.collect` without changing the results. In this case, `l` is still available to access.

And the last `filter` function is more idiomatic to use with [type test operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233220.aspx) `:?`.

```
let GetAllDirectAssignmentsforLists(spWeb: SPWeb) =    
    spWeb.Lists 
    |> Seq.cast<SPList> 
    |> Seq.filter (fun l -> l.HasUniqueRoleAssignments) 
    |> Seq.collect (fun l -> l.RoleAssignments 
                             |> Seq.cast<SPRoleAssignment> 
                             |> Seq.map (fun ra -> ra.Member)
                             |> Seq.filter (fun p -> match box p with
                                                     | :? SPUser -> true
                                                     | _ -> false)
                             |> Seq.map (fun m -> l.Title, m.LoginName.ToLower()))
```

To simplify further, you could change the series of `Seq.map` and `Seq.filter` to [Seq.choose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340250.aspx):

```
Seq.choose (fun ra -> match box ra.Member with
                      | :? SPUser -> Some (l.Title, ra.Member.LoginName.ToLower())
                      | _ -> None)
```

Comment: What is "match box"? is it boxing/unboxing of .NET?

Comment: Yes, it is. It is redundant if your types are reference types. Just include `box` because I don't know your domain of application.

Answer (score 3):

While you can solve the problem by lifting the rest of the computation inside `collect`, I think that you could make the code more readable by using *sequence expressions* instead of pipelining.

I could not run the code to test it, but this should be equivalent:

```
let GetAllDirectAssignmentsforLists (spWeb : SPWeb) = seq {
  // Corresponds to your 'filter' and 'collect'
  for l in Seq.cast<SPList> spWeb.Lists do
    if l.HasUniqueRoleAssignments then
      // Corresponds to nested 'map' and 'filter'
      for ra in Seq.cast<SPRoleAssignment> l.RoleAssignments do
        let m = ra.Member
        if m.GetType().Name = "SPUser" then 
          // This implements the last 'map' operation
          yield l.Title, m.LoginName.ToLower() }
```

The code above corresponds more closely to the version by @pad than to your original code, because the rest of the computation is nested under `for` (which corresponds to nesting under `collect`) and so you can see all variables that are already in scope - like `l` which you need.

The nice thing about sequence expressions is that you can use F# constructs like `if` (instead of `filter`), `for` (instead of `collect`) etc. Also, I think it is more suitable for writing nested operations (which you need here to keep variables in scope), because it remains quite readable and keeps familiar code structure.

Comment: The sequence comprehension syntax `seq { .. }` is perfectly functional feature (and just like C# LINQ, it is inspired by Haskell list comprehensions). I think pipelining is nice for working with other types, but sequence expressions are specifically designed to simplify collection processing, so why not use them? Especially if it makes your code more readable...